# ERRORS & BUILD FAILURE: When executing tests with karma

Tags: java, angular, maven, karma-runner, maven-plugin

When I run mvn install within an Angular project, I get the following error messages and build failures when executing the unit tests:

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.6:karma (run tests) @ test-ui ---
[INFO] Running 'karma start karma.conf.ci.js' in /Users/codehan/Documents/projects/test-ui
[ERROR]
[ERROR] /Users/codehan/Documents/projects/test-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/karma.ts:62
[ERROR] throw new Error(The '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' karma plugin is meant to +
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] Error: The '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' karma plugin is meant to be used from within Angular CLI and will not work correctly outside of it.
```

And some lines below

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.666 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-21T14:31:09+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.6:karma (run tests) on project test-ui: Failed to run task: 'karma start karma.conf.ci.js' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I use the [**frontend-maven-plugin**](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) in the version **1.7.6** and have it inserted like this in my pom.xml.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Frontend plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <nodeVersion>v11.10.0</nodeVersion>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
        ...
```

**My karma.conf.js looks like this:**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), 
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {environment: 'dev'},
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    phantomjsLauncher: {
      // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered (useful if karma
      // exits without killing phantom)
      exitOnResourceError: true
    },    
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**My karma.conf.ci.js like this:**

```
var baseConfig = require('./karma.conf.js');

module.exports = function (config) {
  baseConfig(config);
  config.set({
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher')
    ],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

My pom.xml verion 1 (*Fails with the error: Error: Project 'karma.conf.js' does not support the 'test' target.*)

```
  <execution>
    <id>test</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <arguments>run test --karma-config karma.conf.js</arguments>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
```

My pom.xml version 2 (Fails with the error: *Error: The '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' karma plugin is meant to be used from within Angular CLI and will not work correctly outside of it.*)

```
  <execution>
    <id>run tests</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>karma</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <karmaConfPath>karma.conf.ci.js</karmaConfPath>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
```

**My package.json:**

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --base-href=/ui/",
    "start-local-prod": "ng serve --base-href=/ui/",
    "start-traci": "ng serve --configuration=traci-dev --base-href=/ui/",
    "build": "ng build --prod --base-href=/ui/",
    "build-traci": "ng build --prod --configuration=traci --base-href=/ui/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
...
```

**My angular.json:**

```
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
  "options": {
    "main": "src/test.ts",
    "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"
    ],
...
```

**I use the following versions of the packages:**

**Angular:**

```
"@ angular-devkit / build-angular": "^0.12.4",
"@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
"@Angle/compiler-cli": "7.2.0",
"@angular/core": "7.2.0",
"@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.13.9",
"@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.13.9",
"@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.13.9",
"@angular-devkit/core": "^7.3.9",
```

**Karma**

```
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
"karma mocha reporter": "^2.2.5",
"karma-webpack": "^3.0.5",
```

**Jasmine**

```
"@ types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
"jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
```

**Java**

```
Java version: 1.8.0_201
```

**Maven**

```
Apache Maven 3.6.1
```

**Operating system**

```
MacOS Mojave (Version 10.14.5)
```

**IDE**

```
Visual Studio Code
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

In pom.xml there is this line, which is wrong:

```
    <goals>
      <goal>karma</goal>
    </goals>
```

This is the cause of error: `Running 'karma start karma.conf.ci.js`. This can't be done in that way. Up to Angular 5 it was possible to do it in such a way, but from Angular 6 its not allowed.

The first version of pom is fine, but if it throws error, I would suggest to change it in such way, starting from angular.json:

```
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
             "ci": {
                "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.ci.js"
             },
             "local":{
                "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js"
             }
          }
```

This is the configuration, that `ng test` command will use. So lets also update package.json, this line: `"test": "ng test"` should be changed to this:

```
   "test:local": "ng test --configuration=local",
   "test:ci": "ng test --configuration=ci"
```

And finally pom xml:

```
  <execution>
    <id>test</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <arguments>run test:ci</arguments>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
```

Comment: are you able to add more lines from pom.xml file? I'm wondering what is in execution.

Comment: I've added two version of my pom.xml and the error messages to my question.

Comment: pom.xml version 1 looks ok, version 2 is wrong for sure (here you were calling karma directly, hence the error that I've mentioned - you have to call the command with `npm run test ...`. Do you still have a error if you change this line: `<arguments>run test --karma-config karma.conf.js</arguments>` to this: `<arguments>run test</arguments>`

Comment: The whole answer was changed, please take a look on it.

Comment: I replaced run test --karma-config with run test and introduced ChromeHeadless. Local works now, but not in Jenkins. This error message is thrown: error while loading shared libraries:
libXss.so.1: can not open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I just googled that, and the error message looks like a problem with jenkins (or rather linux that jenkins is run on) than npm or ng problem.